# Creating Huge Low Poly Terrain

Tags: c++, blender, terrain, vertices

I am starting a new project in *C++* using *GLFW* and *GLEW*.

The plan is to have a fairly big Low Poly terrain. It will *NOT* be randomly generated, I am planning on making it in Blender.

My problem is, that I cannot create a **huge** Low Poly terrain in **Blender**, because the program becomes really slow with the amount of vertices that the terrain has. I created a 500m x 500m terrain, and subdivided it by 1000. That gave me *ALOT* of vertices, making the program not usable.

What would be the best approach to creating a huge terrain?
Im not sure how I would go onto creating chunks of the terrain, since I have to model them.

- *How do I create a big Low Poly terrain, without having a problem with
  the program being slow?*

*Another* concern of mine is obviously loading the world into a custom game engine of mine. I suppose a big world like this would have huge problems with the load times.

Comment: Somehow `make less verticies` - so either lower resolution or smaller size -
 seems too obvious?

Comment: I have thought of that, but I don't want to scale my objects too much in my game engine. I'm trying to keep the size in meters, not go down to centimeters :)

Comment: So why can't you make multiple terrains, but each one say 50m x 50m; and then only load the ones you need for what's going on?  Solves your problem with vertex count & load time

Comment: Well that is exactly my question. Creating that many chunks and modeling them to make them all work together is really inefficient, since it would take a lot of time trying to make the transitions be smooth. I am looking for an alternative. :)

Comment: `transitions be smooth` load the next sections earlier.  Who cares if the last little bit of the map is wrong if you can never see/use it? ;)

Comment: True :) But I was talking about the difficulty of actually modeling them :)

Comment: That is a modelling problem, not a coding problem :D

Comment: I suppose you're right :) Thanks for sharing your ideas! :)

Comment: Probably a question for blender.stackexchange.com.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Terrain in game engines like Unity, Unreal Engine and CryEngine is treated differently from your average static or skeletal mesh. Creation of different levels of detail are is usually done at runtime, as opposed to ordinary meshes having their LODs pre-created. Loading a mesh from a 3D program like Blender or 3DS Max as your entire terrain just isn't doable.

The Direct3D tutorials at rastertek are very good for learning, but isn't OpenGL obviously. Here is a basic tutorial of creating a basic terrain in Java OpenGL (This doesn't go into LOD handling I don't think).

[Java OpenGL terrain](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=yNYwZMmgTJk)

Most commonly I think I've seen a quad tree system, where you have terrain patches, and each patch is subdivided into four other patches, depending on a condition (whether distance to camera or screenspace size).

This is what a standard quad-tree LOD system looks like, in particular for the game Kerbal Space Program.

[image]

Along the way you'll need to figure out how to solve some problems, like how to get rid of the cracks and gaps in between two terrain patches that are of different LOD levels. Kerbal Space Program solved this by treating the edge vertices differently to line up, and not allowing any two adjacent terrain patches to be more than one LOD level of difference.

One method I tried was to upload two vertex positions for each vertex, the current LOD position and the position of the LOD vertex from one level down, and linearly interpolate between the two based on camera distance. Yet I'm pretty sure there are more elegant ways than this.

I've posted a video from a while ago of me messing around with this stuff, it shows the basic quad tree pattern, the problem of cracks, and then the vertex interpolation method. Some people create the patches on the CPU and other on the GPU and read back any necessary info, (like for example for physics) using transform feedback. There's lots of ways of doing things, and I hope to get back into it.

[TerrainPatches](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1u0KBS4K18Q-8NuwuaZditM8CrYZ35Fl8/view?usp=sharing)

Comment: Thank you so much for this amazing answer! I love the video that you linked, it really helps me understand some things alot better! Also, I will look into the tutorial you provided  Sorry for the late response btw. Thanks again!

Answer (score 3):

I did something similar many years ago and found this tutorial very helpful:

http://www.rastertek.com/tertut05.html

It describes creating a quad tree with specific triangles from your terrain mesh partitioned into AABBs, using frustum culling huge parts of your terrain can be culled during runtime and your application's performance should improve. As long as you are confident importing meshes exported from blender (are they in .obj ?) you should easily be able to partition the different triangles using the strategies outlined in the tutorial.

A further optimization could be to have various LODs for nodes in your quadtree depending on the distance from the camera, i.e if a node is a set distance from the camera render a lower poly mesh by skipping certain vertices to make the smaller triangles "collapse" into larger ones. I'd recommend generating specific index lists to do this and use the same vertex data as opposed to having separate pre-generated chunks of mesh to save on memory.

Comment: I **LOVE** this approach! Thank you for sharing! This is by far the best tutorial I saw on quad trees, it seems to make the most sense. The only problem being modeling the actual terrain, since it is fairly hard to do so with a huge terrain. :)

Comment: This doesn't appear to have anything to do with the question though, which was about modelling in blender???

Comment: I would have to disagree - "I am starting a new project in C++ using GLFW and GLEW". The approach outlined would allow the poster to create a model how they wish from within blender, taking the pressure from "how do I make this in blender so it's usable" to "don't worry about the method in Blender, just worry about how to treat the exported model information in your engine/renderer"